# Splitting a string into words and punctuation

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to split a string up into words and punctuation, adding the punctuation to the list produced by the split.

For instance:

```
>>> c = "help, me"
>>> print c.split()
['help,', 'me']
```

What I really want the list to look like is:

```
['help', ',', 'me']
```

So, I want the string split at whitespace with the punctuation split from the words.

I've tried to parse the string first and then run the split:

```
>>> for character in c:
...     if character in ".,;!?":
...             outputCharacter = " %s" % character
...     else:
...             outputCharacter = character
...     separatedPunctuation += outputCharacter
>>> print separatedPunctuation
help , me
>>> print separatedPunctuation.split()
['help', ',', 'me']
```

This produces the result I want, but is painfully slow on large files.

Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: For this example (not the general case) `c.replace(' ','').partition(',')`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is more or less the way to do it:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", "Hello, I'm a string!")
['Hello', ',', "I'm", 'a', 'string', '!']
```

The trick is, not to think about where to split the string, but what to include in the tokens.

Caveats:

- The underscore (_) is considered an inner-word character. Replace \w, if you don't want that.
- This will not work with (single) quotes in the string.
- Put any additional punctuation marks you want to use in the right half of the regular expression.
- Anything not explicitely mentioned in the re is silently dropped.

Comment: If you want to split at ANY punctuation, including `'`, try `re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]", "Hello, I'm a string!")`.  The result is `['Hello', ',', 'I', "'", 'm', 'a', 'string', '!']`  Note also that digits are included in the word match.

Comment: Sorry! could you explain how exactly this is working?

Comment: @Curious: to be honest, no I coiuld not. Because, where should I start? What do you know? Which part is a problem for you? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Never mind! I understood this myself! Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 47):

Here is a Unicode-aware version:

```
re.findall(r"\w+|[^\w\s]", text, re.UNICODE)
```

The first alternative catches sequences of word characters (as defined by unicode, so "résumé" won't turn into `['r', 'sum']`); the second catches individual non-word characters, ignoring whitespace.

Note that, unlike the top answer, this treats the single quote as separate punctuation (e.g. "I'm" -> `['I', "'", 'm']`). This appears to be standard in NLP, so I consider it a feature.

Comment: Upvoted because the `\w+|[^\w\s]` construct is more generic than the accepted answer but afaik in python 3 the re.UNICODE shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 13):

If you are going to work in English (or some other common languages), you can use [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) (there are many other tools to do this such as [FreeLing](http://nlp.lsi.upc.edu/freeling/node/1)).

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
sentence = "help, me"
nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
```

Comment: The (original) above code fails for me with an error about needing the PUNKT resource.  I'll suggest an edit to include `nltk.download('punkt')` after `import nltk`.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my entry.

I have my doubts as to how well this will hold up in the sense of efficiency, or if it catches all cases (note the "!!!" grouped together; this may or may not be a good thing).

```
>>> import re
>>> import string
>>> s = "Helo, my name is Joe! and i live!!! in a button; factory:"
>>> l = [item for item in map(string.strip, re.split("(\W+)", s)) if len(item) > 0]
>>> l
['Helo', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Joe', '!', 'and', 'i', 'live', '!!!', 'in', 'a', 'button', ';', 'factory', ':']
>>>
```

One obvious optimization would be to compile the regex before hand (using re.compile) if you're going to be doing this on a line-by-line basis.

Comment: plus 1 for grouping punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
import re

i = 'Sandra went to the hallway.!!'
l = re.split('(\W+?)', i)
print(l)

empty = ['', ' ']
l = [el for el in l if el not in empty]
print(l)

Output:
['Sandra', ' ', 'went', ' ', 'to', ' ', 'the', ' ', 'hallway', '.', '', '!', '', '!', '']
['Sandra', 'went', 'to', 'the', 'hallway', '.', '!', '!']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minor update to your implementation.  If your trying to doing anything more detailed I suggest looking into the NLTK that le dorfier suggested.

This might only be a little faster since ''.join() is used in place of +=, which is [known to be faster](http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/).

```
import string

d = "Hello, I'm a string!"

result = []
word = ''

for char in d:
    if char not in string.whitespace:
        if char not in string.ascii_letters + "'":
            if word:
                    result.append(word)
            result.append(char)
            word = ''
        else:
            word = ''.join([word,char])

    else:
        if word:
            result.append(word)
            word = ''
print result
['Hello', ',', "I'm", 'a', 'string', '!']
```

Comment: i have not profiled this, but i guess the main problem is with the char-by-char concatenation of word. i'd instead use an index and slices.

Comment: With tricks i can shave 50% off the execution time of your solution. my solution with re.findall() is still twice as fast.

Comment: You need to call `if word: result.append(word)` after the loop ends, else the last word is not in result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all the help you can imagine in the [NLTK](http://nltk.org), especially since you are using python. There's a good comprehensive discussion of this issue in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to tokenize all words and `\W+` patterns using `\b` which doesn't need hardcoding:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence = 'Hello, world!'
>>> tokens = [t.strip() for t in re.findall(r'\b.*?\S.*?(?:\b|$)', sentence)]
['Hello', ',', 'world', '!']
```

Here `.*?\S.*?` is a pattern matching anything that is not a space and `$` is added to match last token in a string if it's a punctuation symbol.

Note the following though -- this will group punctuation that consists of more than one symbol:

```
>>> print [t.strip() for t in re.findall(r'\b.*?\S.*?(?:\b|$)', '"Oh no", she said')]
['Oh', 'no', '",', 'she', 'said']
```

Of course, you can find and split such groups with:

```
>>> for token in [t.strip() for t in re.findall(r'\b.*?\S.*?(?:\b|$)', '"You can", she said')]:
...     print re.findall(r'(?:\w+|\W)', token)

['You']
['can']
['"', ',']
['she']
['said']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string_big = "One of Python's coolest features is the string format operator  This operator is unique to strings"
my_list =[]
x = len(string_big)
poistion_ofspace = 0
while poistion_ofspace < x:
    for i in range(poistion_ofspace,x):
        if string_big[i] == ' ':
            break
        else:
            continue
    print string_big[poistion_ofspace:(i+1)]
    my_list.append(string_big[poistion_ofspace:(i+1)])
    poistion_ofspace = i+1

print my_list
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a regex?

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re-syntax

---

By the way. Why do you need the "," at the second one? You will know that after each text is written i.e.

[0]

","

[1]

","

So if you want to add the "," you can just do it after each iteration when you use the array..

Answer (score -1):

In case you are not allowed to import anything,use this!

```
word = "Hello,there"
word = word.replace("," , " ," )
word = word.replace("." , " .")
return word.split()
```