# Split by \b when your regex engine doesn't support it

Tags: python, regex

How can I split by word boundary in a regex engine that doesn't support it?

python's re can match on \b but doesn't seem to support splitting on it. I seem to recall dealing with other regex engines that had the same limitation.

example input:

```
"hello, foo"
```

expected output:

```
['hello', ', ', 'foo']
```

actual python output:

```
>>> re.compile(r'\b').split('hello, foo')
['hello, foo']
```

Comment: it does not only /seem/ to not support it, it says so in the documentation...

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(\W+) can give you the expected output:

```
>>> re.compile(r'(\W+)').split('hello, foo')
['hello', ', ', 'foo']
```

Comment: Because it splits non-word characters, (in this case the whitespace and the comma...), and the capturing parentheses are used in pattern, so the text of the group in the pattern is also returned as part of the resulting list.

Comment: @CMS: You might want to mention the option for a re.U flag, or a "(?u)" prefix in the regex, since we live in a multilingual world.

Comment: re.split(r'(\W+)', '* hello, foo!') gives ['', '* ', 'hello', ', ', 'foo', '!', ''], so you may need to deal with the initial and final empty strings

Answer (score 2):

One can also use re.findall() for this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.+?\b', 'hello, foo')
['hello', ', ', 'foo']
```

Comment: re.findall(r'.+?\b', 'hello, foo!') gives ['hello', ', ', 'foo'], missing the final '!'

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out:

Put the split pattern in capturing parens and will be included in the output. You can use either \w+ or \W+:

```
>>> re.compile(r'(\w+)').split('hello, foo')
['', 'hello', ', ', 'foo', '']
```

To get rid of the empty results, pass it through filter() with None as the filter function, which will filter anything that doesn't evaluate to true:

```
>>> filter(None, re.compile(r'(\w+)').split('hello, foo'))
['hello', ', ', 'foo']
```

Edit: CMS points out that if you use \W+ you don't need to use filter()

Comment: you still need the filter if your string starts or end with a non-word symbol

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> re.compile(r'\W\b').split('hello, foo')
['hello,', 'foo']
```

This splits at the non-word characted before a boundry.
Your example has nothing to split on.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. So far most RE engines I tried do this split.

I played a bit and found that `re.compile(r'(\W+)').split('hello, foo')` is giving the output you expected... Not sure if that's reliable, though.