# Alternative way to extract lines from text (python-regex)

Tags: python, regex, text

I am looking for a way to extract lines from a pretty big database in python. I need to retain only those containing one of my keywords.
I thought I could use regex to solve the problem and I've put together the code below. Unfortunately, it gives me some errors (perhaps also due to the fact that my keywords, which are written in separate lines in the file listtosearch.txt, are indeed large in number, nearly 500).

```
import re
data = open('database.txt').read() 
fileout = open("fileout.txt","w+")

with open('listtosearch.txt', 'r') as f:
    keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(keywords))

for line in data:
    if pattern.search(line):
        fileout.write(line)
```

I've also tried to use a double loop (both in the keywords list and in the lines of the database) but it takes too much time to run.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile 
    return _compile(pattern, flags)   
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 240, in _compile 
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags) 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 511, in compile 
    "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups" 
AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: It gives me these errors: 
pattern = re.compile('|'.join(keywords))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
return _compile(pattern, flags)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 240, in _compile
p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 511, in compile
"sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
AssertionError: sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups

Comment: well there you go, it's telling you you can't have more that 100 sub-expressions in your regex pattern. not your fault. brice's answer will work.

Comment: Actually it gives me exactly the same errors even when I run Brice's code :(

Comment: @user2447387 that's not possible. My code doesn't use the `re` module and I don't have the offending line.

Comment: I know, sorry, my bad! Let me run it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code:

```py
import re
data = open('database.txt', 'r')
fileout = open("fileout.txt","w+")

with open('listtosearch.txt', 'r') as f:
    keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]

# one big pattern can take time to match, so you have a list of them
patterns = [re.compile(keyword) for keyword in keywords]

for line in data:

    for pattern in patterns:
        if not pattern.search(line):
            break
    else:
        fileout.write(line)
```

I tested it with the following files:

database.txt

```
"Name jhon" (1995)
"Name foo" (2000)
"Name fake" (3000)
"Name george" (2000)
"Name george" (2500)
```

listtosearch.txt

```
"Name (george)"
\(2000\)
```

And this is what i get in fileout.txt

```
"Name george" (2000)
```

So this should be working also on you machine.

Comment: I don't know why (sorry, I am a beginner at python) but in this way no line is extracted

Comment: The keywords are in this form: "Name name" (year) and have to be matched entirely (name in "" and year in brackets)

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Then you can loop on line just with an in (like you already do to read keywords, I didn't notice). I modified the snippet to also assure that all the regex are matched.

Comment: :( The output file results empty once again...I really can't figure out why

Comment: You should check your patterns then. It seems that none of the lines in database.txt is matching them all.

Comment: Actually there are some matches.. I'm using a subsample of my dataset to test things out and running a simple double loop seems to work fine (except for the fact that it takes a long time)

Comment: I've added one more else on the inner loop so to avoid useless regex checks

Comment: My bad as usual, sorry! I forgot to escape parenthesis in my keywords list. That must be the issue...Thank you for your patience! :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [Aho–Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). A working implementation in python can be found [here](http://0x80.pl/proj/pyahocorasick/).

A simple example usage of this module :

```
from pyahocorasick import Trie

words = ['foo', 'bar']

t = Trie()
for w in words:
    t.add_word(w, w)
t.make_automaton()

print [a for a in t.iter('my foo is a bar')]

>> [(5, ['foo']), (14, ['bar'])]
```

Integrating in your code should be straightforward.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks, however it seems pretty difficult given my limited notions of python and coding in general :(

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I'm pretty sure that you mean **`data = open('database.txt').readlines()`** rather than `read()`. Otherwise, `data` will be a string rather than a list of lines, and your `for line in data` won't make any sense.

At this point, you're really looking for an indexing solution by keyword, and naive search  will stop being efficient enough to give you a timely result.

There's really not another approach that's significantly more efficient or less complex. You're going to have to grind your teeth and accept the cost of looking through the entire database.

Also, your database can't be all that big if it completely fits in memory :)

That said, there are other ways you could do it that will probably be more efficient:

1. Put your keywords in a set, then tokenise the input data into word and look all of them up in the set:

   ```
   data = open('database.txt').readlines() 
   fileout = open("fileout.txt","w+")

   with open('listtosearch.txt', 'r') as f:
     keywords = [line.strip() for line in f]

   keywords = set(keywords)

   for line in data:
       # You might have to be smarter about splitting the line to 
       # take things like punctuation into consideration.
       for word in line.split():
         if word in keywords:
           fileout.write(line)
           break
   ```

   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation)'s an example of word splitting that takes into account punctuation.

Comment: I don't know why (sorry, I am a beginner at python) but in this way no line is extracted. My keywords are in this form: "name names" (year) and have to be matched entirely for a line to be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be an efficient solution, but try using set and it's intersection properties.

```
from_db = tuple([line.rstrip("\n") for line in open('database.txt') if line.rstrip('\n')])
keywords = set([line.rstrip("\n") for line in open('listtosearch.txt') if line.rstrip('\n')])
with open("output_file.txt", "w") as fp:
    for line in from_db:
        line_set = set(line.split(" "))
        if line_set.intersection(keywords):
            fp.write(line + "\n")
```

Intersection will check for any common strings. Since hash values are compared, I guess the search will be faster rather than running down the entire list again and again.