# how do i break a string into sections python

Tags: python, string, list, split, language-design

How do I break a string into sections in Python?
For example, how do I break

```
IF: /1 =isit= 1\
.show: "1 = 1"
```

into `sections = ['IF:', '/', 1, '=isit=', 1, '\\', '.', 'show:', '"1 = 1"']`

PS. This is for basic language development

Tokens (for now):

1. `IF:` (for if) / (to mark the beginning of an expression, or whatever 1==1 is called)
2. `=is=` (for =)
3. `=isit=` (for ==)
4. `\` (for : at the end)
5. `.` (for a tab)
6. `show:` (for print)
   strings, ints, bools (true and false), and counting.

In other words, things before the : (keywords), after (bools, expressions, objects), and etc.

Comment: What are the rules for how the tokens are supposed to be split?

Comment: You'll probably want to use a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) like [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) or build a grammar using [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/367292/2479481) for a starting point.

Comment: I haven't played with it, but [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) maybe of use

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple solution to this since you can't generalize "split on character X" or "split between characters X and Y".

You will need to write a tokenizer (common synonyms: lexer, parser) that inspects your string character by character (and you will likely need to use state tracking).