# Replace words with word-substitutions from another file

Tags: python, translation, nltk

The words from my text file (mytext.txt) needs to be replaced by some other word provided in another text file (replace.txt)

```
cat mytext.txt
this is here. and it should be there. 
me is this will become you is that.

cat replace.txt
this that
here there
me you
```

The following code does not work as expected.

```
with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as myf:
    with open('replace.txt' , 'r') as myr:
        for line in myf.readlines():
            for l2 in myr.readlines():
                original, replace = l2.split()
                print line.replace(original, replace)
```

Expected output:

```
that is there. and it should be there. 
you is that will become you is that.
```

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: To be clear, I assume the general case is N lines of text, and R replacements, not N=2 lines like the example here. And that you  prefer scalable O(N) code rather than nonscalable code O(NR) where you're looping on each of the R replacements, for each of the N lines.

Comment: Do you care about scalability? Taking it the general case is **N lines of text, and R replacements**, not N=2 lines like the example here. And that you prefer scalable O(N) code rather than nonscalable code O(NR) where you're looping on each of the R replacements, for each of the N lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**  I stand corrected, the OP is asking for word by word replacement rather than simple string replace ('become' -> 'become' rather than 'becoyou').  I guess a dict version might look like this, using the regex split method found on the comments of the accepted answer to  [Splitting a string into words and punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation):

```
import re

def clean_split(string_input):
    """ 
    Split a string into its component tokens and return as list
    Treat spaces and punctuations, including in-word apostrophes as separate tokens

    >>> clean_split("it's a good day today!")
    ["it", "'", "s", " ", "a", " ", "good", " ", "day", " ", "today", "!"]
    """
    return re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\w]", string_input)

with open('replace.txt' , 'r') as myr:
    replacements = dict(tuple(line.split()) for line in myr)

with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as myf:
    for line in myf:
        print ''.join(replacements.get(word, word) for word in clean_split(line)),
```

I am not competent to reason well about `re` efficiency, if someone points out glaring inefficiencies I would be most grateful.

**Edit 2:** OK I was inserting spaces between words and punctuation, now *that's* fixed by treating spaces as tokens and doing a `''.join()` instead of a `' '.join()`

Comment: Won't produce the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the line after one replacement, then printing the line again after the next replacement.  You want to print the line after doing all the replacements.

> str.replace(old, new[, count])
>   Return a *copy* of the string...

You are discarding the copy every time because you don't save it in a variable.  In other words, replace() does not change `line`.

Next, the word `there` contains the substring `here`(which is replaced by `there`), so the result ends up being `tthere`.

You can fix those problems like this:

```
import re

with open('replace.txt' , 'r') as f:
    repl_dict = {}

    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split()
        repl_dict[key] = val


with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for key, val in repl_dict.items():
            line = re.sub(r"\b" + key + r"\b", val, line, flags=re.X)
        print line.rstrip()

--output:--
that is there. and it should be there. 
you is that will become you is that.
```

Or, like this:

```
import re

#Create a dict that returns the key itself
# if the key is not found in the dict:
class ReplacementDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = key
        return key

#Create a replacement dict:
with open('replace.txt') as f:
    repl_dict = ReplacementDict()

    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split()
        repl_dict[key] = val

#Create the necessary inputs for re.sub():
def repl_func(match_obj):
    return repl_dict[match_obj.group(0)]

pattern = r"""
    \w+   #Match a 'word' character, one or more times
"""

regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.X)

#Replace the words in each line with the 
#entries in the replacement dict:
with open('mytext.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub(regex, repl_func, line)
        print line.rstrip())
```

With replace.txt like this:

```
this that
here there
me you
there dog
```

...the output is:

```
that is there. and it should be dog.
you is that will become you is that.
```

Comment: `the word there contains the substring here` good point, @7stud. So we need to split each line into words and do the replacements word by word.

Comment: ... or use regexes. :) FWIW, I haven't submitted fully working code myself because I suspect that this is homework, so I prefer to just give helpful hints.

Answer (score 1):

The following will solve your problem. The problem with your code is that you are printing after each replacement.

The optimal solution will be:

```
myr=open("replace.txt")
replacement=dict()
for i in myr.readlines():
    original,replace=i.split()
    replacement[original]=replace
myf=open("mytext.txt")
for i in myf.readlines():
    for j in i.split():
        if(j in replacement.keys()):
            i=i.replace(j,replacement[j])
    print i
```

Comment: It does not change the second line :(

Comment: 'become' changes to 'becoyou' because it contains the character 'me'. Adding nltk tag to find more options.

Comment: @shantanuo: This task doesn't require `nltk` - it can be easily done with standard `str` methods, or Regular Expressions.

Comment: With a very large file, I get "MemoryError" while using regular expression. The string method works - but 'become' changes to 'becoyou'. So let us try nltk.

Comment: @shantanuo: I solved the problem in the above code but it's inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want your inner loop to read the contents of 'replace.txt' for each line of 'mytext.txt'. That's very inefficient, and it won't actually work as written because once you've read all the lines of 'replace.txt' the file pointer is left at the end of the file, so when you try to process the 2nd line of 'mytext.txt' there won't be any lines left to read in 'replace.txt'.

You *could* send the myr file pointer back to the start of the file using `myr.seek(0)`, but as I said, that's not very efficient. A much better strategy is to read 'replace.txt' into an appropriate data structure, and then use that data to do your replacements on each line of 'mytext.txt'.

A good data structure to use for this would be a `dict`. Eg,

```
replacements = {'this': 'that', 'here': 'there', 'me': 'you'}
```

Can you figure out how to build such a dict from 'replace.txt'?

I see that gman and 7stud have covered the issue of saving the results of your replacements so that they accumulate, so I won't bother discussing that. :)

Comment: Yes, as long as all the from-strings are disjoint, which they should be. Translating with a dict is much faster than `re.sub()`, especially repeated `re.sub()`s.

Comment: Why would you say that a dict is the right data structure to use here, rather than a list of tuples?  In any implementation I can think of except regex, I need to iterate through the keys and then refer to the values via key, or use .iteritems, both of which is more cumbersome and inefficient than simply using a list of tuples from beginning to end.

Comment: @zehnpaard: Well, I originally suggested a dict because dict lookup is fast. But as smci mentioned it wouldn't work so well if the from strings are not disjoint. Your list of tuples could handle that if the tuples were sorted appropriately. Eg [('here', 'there'), ('he', 'she'),...]. But you'd still have to make sure that you didn't perform multiple replacements on a given word.

Comment: @zehnpaard: because dict lookup is O(1) whereas list/tuple lookup is O(N). Less scalable. No you don't need to iterate through each of the keys! You directly lookup the dict with each word of from-text, and that tells you the replacement-word, if any. In general when you find yourself iterating over a dict is a code smell that you probably don't need to.

Comment: I agree dict lookups are fast, but only if you're not unpacking the dict into a tuple and then using that.  If you start doing `for key, val in dict.iteritems():` or `for key in dict:` then there's no efficiency benefit.

Comment: @zehnpaard: **Never iterate over a dict where you can avoid iterating (which is 99+% of the time)!** Use simple lookup, already. Purge `dict.items()/dict.iteritems()` wherever possible! It's that simple.

Comment: @smci yes I agree with that fully, but I couldn't see an easy way of using just dict lookups in this example.  Which was why I advocated against dicts entirely.  Any pointers?

Comment: Just form one unified dict of all possible replacements, like @PM2Ring  has already posted.

Answer (score 1):

here you go using `re.sub`:

```
>>> with open('mytext.txt') as f1, open('replace.txt') as f2:
...     my_text = f1.read()
...     for x in f2:
...         x=x.strip().split()
...         my_text = re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % x[0],x[1],my_text)
...     print my_text
... 
that is there. and it should be there. 
you is that will become you is that.
```

`\b%s\b` defines the word boundaries

Comment: It's inefficient to use repeated `re.sub()`s where one simple dict translation would work, as @PM2Ring points out.

Comment: you use dict translation on whole words, i.e. the output of `line.split()`. If the whole word does not occur in the dict, no translation happens. And you get a huge speed advantage from not looping on all possible substitutions, as well as not repeatedly needing to match '\b'.

Comment: Noone ever said it was "two lines of text", that's just a simplified example the OP gave. In general it'll be N lines of text, and R replacements. There is zero reason to write nonscalable code O(NR) if you could write scalable code O(N) in the same amount of time and without compromising clarity (as in this case). So there's a little O(R) overhead to set up the dict. This is all way better than O(NR).

Comment: Hackaholic, you generally don't "search" (or iterate over) a dict, you look it up. That's why it's a dict! ;-)

Comment: Hackaholic, like I just wrote to @zehnpaard: **Never iterate over a dict where you can avoid iterating (which is 99+% of the time)!** Use simple lookup, already. Purge `dict.keys()/dict.items()/dict.iteritems()` wherever possible! It's that simple.

Comment: Hackaholic, you should apologize for the ^^ obnoxious comment.

Comment: i am not in conversation anymore

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we may use **string's template** to achieve this, it works but *VERY* ugly and inefficient though:

```
from string import Template

with open('replace.txt', 'r') as myr:
    # read the replacement first and build a dictionary from it
    d = {str(k): v for k,v in [line.strip().split(" ") for line in myr]}

d
{'here': 'there', 'me': 'you', 'this': 'that'}

with open('mytext.txt', 'r') as myf:
    for line in myf:
        print Template('$'+' $'.join(line.strip().replace('$', '_____').\
                  split(' '))).safe_substitute(**d).\
                  replace('$', '').replace('_____', '')
```

Results:

```
that is there. and it should be there.
you is that will become you is that.
```