# Obfuscate Data in .csv from a .txt file

Tags: python, csv

I would like to obfuscate words that occur in a column of a .csv file based on a list of data to remove that are in a different .txt file.

Ideally I will be able to ignore the case of my data and then in the .csv file, replace the matching words from the "to remove" file with an `'*'`. I am not sure what the best method would be to replace the words in the .csv file while also ignoring case. What I have so far isn't working and I am open to solutions.

Example Data file:

```
This is a line of text in .csv column that I want to remove a word from or data such as 123 from.
```

My .txt file will be a list of data to remove:

```
want
remove
123
```

Output should be:

```
This is a line of text in .csv column that I **** to ****** a word or data such as *** from.
```

My code:

```
import csv

with open('MyFileName.csv' , 'rb') as csvfile, open ('DataToRemove.txt', 'r') as removetxtfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        csv_words = row[3].split(" ") #Gets the word for the 4th column in .csv file
            for line in removetxtfile:
                for wordtoremove in line.split():
                    if csv_words.lower() ==  wordtoremove.lower()
                        csv_words = csv_words.replace(wordtoremove.lower(), '*' * len(csv_words))
```

Comment: I think you're trying to condense this code into too many loops to the point of inefficiency. You use `row[3].split(" ")`; does this mean that the _only_ words/phrases that you want to obfuscate are in sentences in that column? Also, what is the the actual output? Everything here is read in but nothing else.

Comment: Yes, the rest of the columns of data don't have the words/phrases that I wish to obfuscate. I was thinking that this many nested for loops wasn't going to be efficient, however, I'm new to Python and am not sure what the better method would be. My actual output should take the words (ignoring case) from my .txt file that occur anywhere in the column of the .csv file and replace the matching words in the .csv column with an '*'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by constructing a set of censor words. My input is basically a plain text file of newline separated words. If your text file is different you might need to parse separately.

Other thoughts:

Create a separate censored file output instead of trying to overwrite your input file. That way if you screw up your algorithm you don't lose your data.

You do a `.split(" ")` on the 4th column, which is only necessary if there are multiple words, space separated, in that column. If that is not the case, you can skip the `for w in csv_words` loop, which loops over all the words in the 4th column.

```
import csv
import re
import string

PUNCTUATION_SPLIT_REGEX = re.compile(r'[\s{}]+'.format(re.escape(string.punctuation)))

# construct a set of words to censor
censor_words = set()
with open ('DataToRemove.txt', 'r') as removetxtfile:
  for l in removetxtfile:
    words = PUNCTUATION_SPLIT_REGEX.split(l)
    for w in words:
        censor_words.add(w.strip().lower())

with open('MyFileName.csv' , 'rb') as csvfile, open('CensoredFileName.csv', 'w') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        csv_words = row[3].split(' ') #Gets the word for the 4th column in .csv file
        new_column = []
        for w in csv_words:
            if w.lower() in censor_words:
                new_column.append('*'*len(w))
            else:
                new_column.append(w)
        row[3] = ' '.join(new_column)
        f.write(' '.join(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: Might want to talk about trimming/ignoring punctuation, too?

Comment: sure. added some split by punctuation. that part is not tested though btw ymmv

Comment: James, this is so close! On my end, I did change the last line to return comma delimiter. However, I failed to consider that my data in the 4th column contains commas and new lines within some of the rows. Good thing you pointed out to create a new file instead. What would be the best approach on how to handle data with commas and new lines in it, yet still be able to upload via a comma delimited file?

Comment: Switching filetype to a .tsv and the last line to `f.write('\t'.join(row) + '\n')` seemed to resolve the issue of commas within data being a concern, it's a workaround. Newlines still cause an issue.

Comment: wait your input file has commas as well as new lines? are they wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Only the strings of data with commas and newlines are wrapped in double quotes. Sorry, I should have clarified that.

Comment: yea my regex strips punctuation. use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation