# How to find every 'x' in a txt file in a python code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text

I have this text file:

> hello world
>
> world hello world

This is my code:

```
f = open("dummy.txt","r+")
x = 0
for line in f:
    if "world" in line:
        x = x + 1
print x
f.close()
```

but it prints `2` and not `3`.

Comment: It prints 2 and not 3 because there are only 2 lines that contain "world".

Comment: you shouldn't use read/write mode on text files.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

```
if "world" in line:
    x = x + 1
```

adds 1 if at least one occurrence is in the line. But there are 2 occurrences in a line, so counting fails.

Just do:

```
x += line.count("world")
```

one-liner using `sum` and a comprehension:

```
sum(line.count("world") for line in f)
```

note that word boundaries are not respected. Substrings also match. Consider using `line.split().count("world")` instead, even if it doesn't properly splits on punctuation. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation) to split on punctuation properly.

Answer (score 2):

```
F = open("Dummy.txt", "r+")
string = F.read() # For storing the file as a string
print string.count("world") # Print the count of "world" in the file
F.close()
```

Comment: yeah, why reading lines when you can count on the whole file. That said, works if the file is reasonably large. If the file is huge, reading line by line is better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are doing

```
for line in f:
    if "world" in line:
        x=x+1
```

One way to fix this problem is to count every instance of "world" in a line.

```
for line in f:
    if "world" in line:
        x+=line.count("world")
```

Another way to is count every individual word.

```
for line in f:
    for word in line.split():
        if word == "world":
            x+=1
```

For next time please remember that:
1.     for line in f: takes it as a whole line not one word and if there are multiple instances of a word in that line your code only counts how many lines has the word.
2. A tip that you might like is that x=x+1 says that x is equal to the value x plus 1. If I were you I will take a look at this
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm 
it teaches you how to use the basic operators which can save a lot of time and frustration. In your example x+=1 is the same as x=x+1.

Good Luck!