# How would I reverse each word individually rather than the whole string as a whole

Tags: python-3.x, reverse

I'm trying to reverse the words in a string individually so the words are still in order however just reversed such as "hi my name is" with output "ih ym eman si" however the whole string gets flipped

```
    r = 0
    def readReverse(): #creates the function
        start = default_timer() #initiates a timer
        r = len(n.split()) #n is the users input
        if len(n) == 0:
            return n
        else:
            return n[0] + readReverse(n[::-1])
            duration = default_timer() - start
            print(str(r) + " with a runtime of " + str(duration))

    print(readReverse(n))
```

Comment: How do you want to handle the punctuation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the string into words, punctuation and whitespace with a regular expression [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8930959/6220679). Then you can use a generator expression to reverse each word individually and finally join them together with `str.join`.

```
import re


text = "Hello, I'm a string!"
split_text = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[^\w]", text)

reversed_text = ''.join(word[::-1] for word in split_text)
print(reversed_text)
```

Output:

```
olleH, m'I a gnirts!
```

---

If you want to ignore the punctuation you can omit the regular expression and just split the string:

```
text = "Hello, I'm a string!"

reversed_text = ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in text.split())
```

However, the commas, exclamation marks, etc. will then be a part of the words.

```
,olleH m'I a !gnirts
```

---

Here's the recursive version:

```
def read_reverse(text):
    idx = text.find(' ')  # Find index of next space character.
    if idx == -1:  # No more spaces left.
        return text[::-1]
    else:  # Split off the first word and reverse it and recurse.
        return text[:idx][::-1] + ' ' + read_reverse(text[idx+1:])
```

Comment: How would i implement this recursively, when attempting to return the function python output 'none'

Comment: I've added a recursive version.