# How to use python regexp module in julia

Tags: python, julia

I want to use a specific regexp given in python in Julia. To do so, I add the PyCall.jl package. Unfortunately, I could not convert the following piece of python code to Julia

## Python [version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367292/5223033):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", "Hello, I'm a string!")
['Hello', ',', "I'm", 'a', 'string', '!']
```

## My trial on Julia:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport re
re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", "Hello, I'm a string!")
```

I got an error stating:

```
ERROR: PyError (ccall(@pysym(:PyObject_Call), PyPtr, (PyPtr, PyPtr, PyPtr), o, arg, C_NULL)) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'> 
TypeError('first argument must be string or compiled pattern',)
```

Comment: What does `r` prefix do in Julia?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I guess it means the following expression will be regexp

Comment: It's a string macro for regular expressions.

Comment: Perhaps try removing it and just pass in the string that Python expects. I doubt it can handle a Julia regex. You'll probably need to double the backslashes.

Comment: I couldn't understand your suggestion. but I tried `re.findall("[\w']+|[.,!?;]", "Hello, I'm a string!")` if this is what you mentioned. In that case, I cannot get the same result as I get in python

Comment: It returns 3 punctuations which are `, ' !`

Comment: Perhaps `"[\\w']+|[.,!?;]"`? Also, you have to tag me in a comment for me to get a notification about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Base.@raw_str` [non standard string literal macro](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/metaprogramming/#Non-Standard-String-Literals-1):

```rb
julia> using PyCall: @pyimport

julia> @pyimport re

julia> regex = raw"[\w']+|[.,!?;]"
"[\\w']+|[.,!?;]"

julia> re.findall(regex, "Hello, I'm a string!")
6-element Array{String,1}:
 "Hello"
 ","
 "I'm"
 "a"
 "string"
 "!"

julia>
```

Comment: what is non standard string literal macro can you explain it?

Comment: @zwlayer I have added a link to the documentation of non standard string literal macros, but basically `raw"[\w']+|[.,!?;]"`is a macro so this is also equivalent; `@raw_str("[\w']+|[.,!?;]")`. If you have more doubts about those, please create a new question, cheers!