# How to create dictionary of all words, not string by string in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import re
import numpy as np
with open('cat_sentences.txt') as f:
    lines = sum(1 for line in f)
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower())
        L = []
        L.append(re.split('[^a-z]', line.lower()))
        L1 = []
        for element in L:
            for simbol in element:
                if simbol != '':
                  L1.append(simbol)
        wcount = 0
        D = dict()
        for element in L1:
             if element not in D:
                    D[element] = wcount 
                    wcount += 1
             else: 
                D.pop(element)
        print D
```

I need to create dictionary in Python, comprised of all the words from the text with no empty spaces and symbols other than letters. Later I will need to create matrix M x N, where M is the amount of strings in the original text, and N is the number of words in dictionary. My code is as follows:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting a string into words and punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this on (if I right understood what you need):

```
import re
from collections import Counter
text = 'Hello this is text - yes it is'
text_list = re.split('[^a-z]+', text.lower())
count = Counter(text_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(count, index=[0])
```

In this case, you will get next dataframe:

```
hello   is  it  text    this    yes
   1     2   1   1        1      1
```

Or maybe you need next vectorization (but what values will you need?):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
text_list = []
with open('cat_sentences.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        text_list.append(line.lower().replace('[^\w\s]',' '))
        print(text_list)
tfidf_v = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words= None)
X = tfidf_v.fit_transform(text_list)
data = pd.DataFrame(data=X.toarray(), columns=tfidf_v.get_feature_names(), index = text_list)
```

In this case, you will get dataframe where row will be row in text, columns name will be world, and values - frequency (you can read here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)