# Replace regex with regex in string python

Tags: python, regex, nltk

I am new to regular expressions in python. I want to split strings based on delimiters. But the delimiters should also be returned as elements. Such as

```
Input - "The man.in the. high castle." 
Output - ["The", "man", ".", "in", "the", ".", "high", "castle", "."]
```

or

```
Input - "The man-in the. high castle!"
Output - ["The", "man", "-", "in", "the", ".", "high", "castle", "!"]
```

Please note that I am not only trying to split sentences based on white space, delimiters but also return the delimiters. This is somewhat similar to nltk.word_tokenize, but different because word_tokenize cannot split words such as "man.in".

My set of delimiters are ".","?","!", "," and whitespace
Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Splitting a string into words and punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/), I think there are all answers you need.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much

Comment: What does "Replace regex with regex in string python" mean? I can't quite get what you meant.