# How can I split a string maintaining the punctuation? (Python)

Tags: python, string, split

How can I split a string in python taking into account the punctuation in the result?

The following code:

```
s = "Hello, my name is Robert."
s_splitted = s.split()
```

will give as output:

```
["Hello,","my","name","is","Robert."]
```

How can I obtain the following result?

```
["Hello",",","my","name","is","Robert","."]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting a string into words and punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation)

Comment: @ironkey oh thanks, I didn't find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Regex can handle this.

```
import re

s = "Hello, my name is Robert."
s_splitted = [part for part in re.split(r'\b|\s', s) if part != '']
# ['Hello', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Robert']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367155/splitting-a-string-into-words-and-punctuation) answer your question?

So in your case:

```
import re

s = "Hello, my name is Robert."
items = re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", s)
```