# Beautiful Soup adding multiple tags to words in paragraph

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to add a ruby tag  for every word in a paragraph. The html doc looks somthing like this

```
<div class = "bodyTxt">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no postea maiorum sadipscing quo, ad illum percipitur 
    inciderint usu. Rebum vidisse apeirian an vel. Vis nostro iudicabit instructior ex, ne eos 
    facer iudicabit. Nec ludus ridens facete ea, ad vix populo adversarium, te mel meis malis 
    mundi.
 </p>
 <p>Putant omittam no qui, ei sed esse saperet. Te alii unum ignota has, vix ei maiestatis 
    expetendis. Et error iracundia argumentum vim, mel maiestatis delicatissimi ex. Sit altera 
    vivendo ad, vis dolorem consetetur et, fabulas admodum sadipscing te est. Sit et senserit 
    consequuntur interpretaris, et sale ornatus consequat has, modus aeque omittantur has te.
 </p>
</div>
```

and after I want it to look like this

```
  <div class = "bodyTxt">
 <p><ruby>Lorem</ruby> <ruby>ipsum </ruby><ruby>dolor</ruby> <ruby>sit</ruby> 
    <ruby>amet</ruby>,<ruby>no</ruby> <ruby>postea</ruby> <ruby>maiorum</ruby> 
    <ruby>sadipscing/<ruby> <ruby>quo</ruby>, 
    <ruby>ad</ruby> <ruby>illum</ruby> <ruby>percipitur<ruby> 
 </p>
 <p><ruby>Putant</ruby> <ruby>omittam</ruby> <ruby>no</ruby> <ruby>qui</ruby>, <ruby>ei</ruby> 
    <ruby>sed</ruby> <ruby>esse</ruby> <ruby>saperet</ruby>
</div>
```

What i tried to do is first get the text from the bodyText class then just add the tags but problem is it is only adding the tags at the begging and end of each paragraph

```
 for textSection in bodyText.stripped_strings:
    RubyTag = soup.new_tag('ruby')
    RubyTag.string = textSection
    textSection.replace_with(RubyTag)
```

I also tried iterating through the paragraphs and just getting every word and adding the tags like so

```
for textSection in bodyText.stripped_strings:
  for word in textSection:
    RubyTag = soup.new_tag('ruby')
    RubyTag.string = word
    textSection.replace_with(RubyTag)
```

but this throws an error **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'replace_with'**

Comment: replace_with is a tag method  but you are calling it on the stripped string.

Comment: ah okay I see now why i'm getting that error. But still how would I solve the issue of adding a ruby tag to every word in the paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) one way might be to leverage `new_tag()` and `decompose()`. As you want to treat punctuation also within separate tags then regex can be used to generate the content for each new `ruby` tag. I used the regex from [@user3850](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367292/6241235).

Create a new `p` tag, during a loop, and append your `ruby` tags, you can then `decompose()` the original `p` tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = '''<div class = "bodyTxt">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no postea maiorum sadipscing quo, ad illum percipitur 
    inciderint usu. Rebum vidisse apeirian an vel. Vis nostro iudicabit instructior ex, ne eos 
    facer iudicabit. Nec ludus ridens facete ea, ad vix populo adversarium, te mel meis malis 
    mundi.
 </p>
 <p>Putant omittam no qui, ei sed esse saperet. Te alii unum ignota has, vix ei maiestatis 
    expetendis. Et error iracundia argumentum vim, mel maiestatis delicatissimi ex. Sit altera 
    vivendo ad, vis dolorem consetetur et, fabulas admodum sadipscing te est. Sit et senserit 
    consequuntur interpretaris, et sale ornatus consequat has, modus aeque omittantur has te.
 </p>
</div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for t in soup.select('.bodyTxt > p'):
    
    parent = soup.new_tag('p')
    t.insert_after(parent)
    
    for i in [j for j in re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]", t.text)]:
        new_tag = soup.new_tag('ruby')
        new_tag.string = i
        parent.append(new_tag)
    t.decompose()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: dear QHarr many thanks for this great example that contains lots of stuff for learners. This is awesome.  Keep up the great work - helping learners with your  great answers.